# Redirect url and mask domain using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to make a little tweak so i will able to hold 2 domains in 1 hosting, but what i missing - can't mask the url in address bar.
that what i mean: i have 2 domains - test1.com and test2.com
test1.com located in / (root) directory and test2 content located in /subdir/

i used this to redirect all request from test2.com to the /subdir/ using htaccess redirect 301:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test2.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test2.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://test1.com/subdir/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

that's working fine, but what i got in address is: http://test1.com/subdir/
how can i mask/rewrite this address url so it will shown as http://test2.com  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test2\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /test2.com/index.html [NC,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|ico)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test2\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule !^(test2\.com|stylesheets|js)/ /test2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: not good enough.. actually my "subdir" is named "test2.com" When i changed it to property name i now redirected correctly but in address i got test2.com/test2.com

Comment: Do you have any other rule in this .htaccess OR any other .htaccess?

Comment: no, only those:        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test2\.com$ [NC]
  Rewritecomle !^test2.com/ test2.com [NC,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: I mean is there any .htaccess in `/test2.com/` folder also?

Comment: Also see updated code, copy/paste as is and make sure to test in a different browser to avoid 301 caching issues.

Comment: yes, now it's good, but another problem, it trying to look for /test2.com/index.php  and i use there index.html

Comment: You can put `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` line at the top of this .htaccess

Comment: No, i have root /index.php  and in my subdomain/index.html  , still trying to get /subdomain/index.php

Comment: also i tried to do RewriteRule !^test2.com/ /test2.com/index.html , it works, but all of my css/js not loading now :(

Comment: Looks better, but still no css loaded: The requested URL /stylesheets/animate.css was not found on this server.

Comment: `/stylesheets/animate.css` shouldn't get impacted by above rule since I have `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|ico)$ [NC]` Can you clear your browser cache and re-test OR use a different browser to test.

Comment: no, just the same. but i found the solution - i changed all my css link to /test2.com/stylesheets/animate.css and it working now. thanks for your help!